# Unable to SSH into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Network error - Connection timed out

Tags: 20.04, ssh, raspberrypi

Headless Raspberry pi 4 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

SSH was working until it suddenly kicked me out and I've since been unable to get back in. I was in the middle of installing and configuring nextcloud. It's serving webpages that I can access in browsers, and ping shows no packet loss or latency.

Do I need to start from scratch, or is there something I can do to get ssh working again?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a firewall rule was enabled that blocks ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply user10489, but no firewall changes at that time.  Earlier I had enabled ufw, but that didn't block ssh right off the bat. It didn't drop until much later. Just in case, next time I think I'll allow OpenSSH.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an answer to this scenario. I'm going to have to start from scratch reinstalling everything starting with ubuntu. As for preventative measures, I'm going to allow OpenSSH in ufw and install a desktop environment.